# socket.io: 404 errors in javascript console

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, http-status-code-404

In google chrome, `example.com/socket.io` gives 404 errors.
So it seems like my socket.io configuration has errors.
I have no idea what they are.
Here are the most important bits of my node.js server:

**Server.js**

```
"use strict";
/** Imported modules */
const express = require("express");
const server = express();
var app = require("http").createServer(server);

const io = require("socket.io")(app);

const request = require("./modules/request.js");
const db = require("./modules/database.js")(bcrypt, sequelize);
const io_control = require("./modules/io_control.js")(io, db, sequelize);

/** Page Control Modules */
const PageConfig = require("./modules/page/PageConfig.js");
const CommonItems = require("./modules/page/CommonItems.js");

server.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
io.origins("*:*");
const Port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(Port);

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
  console.log(true);
});
```

**io_control.js**

```
module.exports = (io, db, sequelize) => {
  var controller = new IOControl(io, db, sequelize);

  io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    console.log(true);
    //and a lot of other code inside here.
  });
};
```

On client side: it goes like this:

**First script**

```
<script src="/socket.io" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

**Second script**

```
const socket = io('//web.namei.nl',{path: '/socket.io'},{transports: ['websocket'], upgrade: false}).connect('', {query: `uuid=${getCookie('uuid')}&type=${getCookie('type')}` });
```

I tried altering both scripts, no result.

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION: Get [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/), or [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) to verify whether you can connect to the server you want, with the URL you want.

Comment: Please share your client code that connects to the socket.io server

Comment: @SamuelG Just did that, edited the question :)

Comment: So this is is the location of server: `//web.namei.nl` ?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a 404 due to the socket.io client script source path: `src="/socket.io"` which is probably not resolving as the path does not seem valid.

Either use a [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io), point to the location at your IO server like: `//web.namei.nl/socket.io/socket.io.js` or download and include the file in your client directly or using a bundler.

**UPDATE after additional comments from OP**

If you are unable to connect to the socket server and are sure the URL is correct, then:

1. As you are using express to host your IO, you should enable [CORS](https://github.com/expressjs/cors)
2. Try connect without using websockets as the transport as there may be a limitation at your hosting service.
3. Ensure you connect options are configured correctly - they don't appear to be correct.
4. Only use `io.origins` if you want to limit which domains can access the server.

**At server:**

```
const cors = require('cors');
...
const app = express();
app.use(cors());

const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
   ...
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
http.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listening on ${port}`);
});
```

**Client:**

```
// ensure the URL including port are correct below, also first connect without the additional query option
const socket = io('https://web.namei.nl', {
   query: `uuid=${getCookie('uuid')}&type=${getCookie('type')}`
});

socket.on('connection', () => {
   console.info('connected');
});
```

Comment: I tried both of them. When I did, I got 404 errors in the console like `https://web.namei.nl/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mx18Wp-`. Maybe it isn't even my fault, and it relies on the webhosting provider.

Comment: Try remove websocket transport in your connection options

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: The connect statement syntax looks incorrect, I am updating the answer